# getting null values from the collection

Tags: php, laravel

I have an array that comes from an API request that has the stucture below.

```
^ array:40 [
  "id" => 2
  ...
  "categories" => array:2 [
    "data" => array:15 [
      0 => array:3 [
        "id" => 6
        "name" => array:1 [
          "en" => "General"
        ]
        "on_request" => 0
      ]
      1 => array:3 [
        "id" => 14
        "name" => array:1 [
          "en" => "Tuts"
        ]
        "on_request" => 0
      ]
      2 => array:3 [
        "id" => 3
        "name" => array:1 [
          "en" => "Laravel"
        ]
        "on_request" => 0
      ]
      
      ...
  ]
  ...
 ]
```

The array has a 'categories' key and I want to get each category here and store it on a json column on the posts table.

I was trying like this:

```
dd(collect($postInformation)->pluck('categories'));
```

But it shows

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1435
  #items: array:40 [
    0 => null
    1 => null
    2 => null
    ...
```

Do you know how to properly achieve this?

Comment: Can you clearly add the  final output that you need

Comment: Well I need to store the result on a json db column. So probably something like {General, Tuts, Laravel,...). Thanks

Comment: I think you where adding tags to some kind of post or something right... I suggest you to... Make a belongs to many relationships in data base level.. . So you can just send tag ids to backend form frontend api...... If its not possible way to change database structure.... You can use casting in laravel to achieve this...

Comment: Thanks but like that it will create a more complex db structure, is not ok to just create a json column instead?

Comment: Ok.... Then just filter it in frontend it will be much easier....or if you have planed to does this on backend..  Use collection flatten and look the data.... You need to write your own logic to get those values

Comment: why not just ```$postInformation['categories']['data']```

Comment: But like that it returns like this:
 array:15 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "id" => 6
    "name" => array:1 [
      "en" => "General"
    ]
    "on_request" => 0
  ]
  1 => array:3 [
    "id" => 14
    "name" => array:1 [
      "en" => "Tuts"
    ]
    "on_request" => 0
  ]
But I need to store each label (General, Tuts, etc) in a json db column of the posts table.

Comment: Please add the desired outcome to your question. I don't see why you can't format the data after extracting the categories.

Comment: So the result should be stored on a json db column. So it should be the json object with all categories names like:  {General, Tuts, Laravel,...}.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not understanding what is missing in the question, I have the input array the tI have and need to store only the categories in a json db column. So I'm not understanding what is missing in the question, can you explain? Thanks